# Getting the text of selected item on multiSelect.js

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I'm currently using [multiSelect.js](http://loudev.com/#usage) for my select and I'm having a trouble with getting the `text`. I already looked on their documentation but I can't find it.
Here is my current code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="oum_list" name="oum_list[]">
  <option value='1'>elem 1</option>
  <option value='2'>elem 2</option>
  <option value='2'>elem 3</option>
  <option value='3'>elem 4</option>
</select>
<script>
 $('#oum_list').multiSelect({
       afterSelect: function (values) {
            $.toast({
                   heading: 'Added ' + values + ' to list.',
                   text: '',
                   position: 'top-right',
                   loaderBg: '#ff6849',
                   icon: 'success',
                   hideAfter: 3500
            });
        },
        afterDeselect: function (values) {
            $.toast({
                    heading: values + ' remove from list.',
                    text: '',
                    position: 'top-right',
                    loaderBg: '#ff6849',
                    icon: 'success',
                    hideAfter: 3500
            });
        }
  });
  var oum_url = "@Url.Action("OUM_List","Dropdown")";
  $.get(oum_url, function (e) {
       $.each(e, function (i, v) {
             $('#oum_list').multiSelect('addOption', { value: v.ID, text: v.Description, label: v.Description });
       });
       $('#oum_list').multiSelect('refresh');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. What text?

Comment: can we have jsfiddle link?

Comment: I'll add it in a few minutes, my bad

Comment: In the code where you are trying to getting the text ?